# When I'm trying to add line-height; ?px; it's messing up the page

Tags: html, css

how can I add scrolling line and don't mess up the "background-color: lightblue;" and Text?

Here's my code.

This one is with out Line-height:;

And the one bellow is with Line-height:;

[image: With out "Line-Height"]

[image: With "Line-Height"]

```css
body {
    background:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FublnoqeXmRr-umcsK7k6BigiEm3bnXe7i4ILdUjXmhW795Qm05hXyxJGoPReN54Fif7KW1L8RoOrW9xzIIAxIh_WwOtOLwG-tByGKaOV_htONJ8gBJma1MYGOdlLJ1hlTrGZGwG);
background-size: cover;
}

.heading {
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 1160px;

padding: 1px 100px 5px 100px;
}

.heading1 { 
color: black;
font-size: 25px;
 }

 .name {
    font-size: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="heading">
    <p class="heading1">WELCOME TO</p>
    <p class="name">G U L F   S H O R E S</p>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you want to center content?

Comment: I want it so you can scroll down but nothing changes except for the image.

Did you see how it changed when I used Line-height? the whole page just became "Welcome to". and I want do avoid that, is there anyway to make it so I can just scroll down with out it changing stuff?

Comment: where you are adding the line-height ?

Comment: I'm adding it in Body{}

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to achieve here, do you want the "Welcome to GulfShores" to stick in one place on the screen even when you scroll down or what?